# Calculating scale of an image

Tags: scale, geospatial, geo, algebra

I'm working on processing some geo-spatial raster data, JOG-A raster to be exact and know the imagery is supposed to be to a scale of 1:250000, however I would like to calculate this in code but am not coming up with the correct values so thought I would ask for some help.

Here are the bounds of a single image and other values needed for calculations.
(coordinates are in degrees, EPSG:4326)

- Meters Per Degree: 111319.49079327358
- Image Size: x: 1536 y: 1536
- DPI: 90
- Upper Left: 
     Longitude: -89.54314720812182 Latitude: 33.6529242569511
- Upper Right:
     Longitude: -88.8578680230458 Latitude: 33.6529242569511
- Bottom Right:
     Longitude: -88.8578680230458 Latitude: 33.13518696069031
- Bottom Left:
     Longitude: -89.54314720812182 Latitude: 33.13518696069031

I thought I could say:
(degLatA - degLatB) * meterPerDeg / imageSizeY * dpi / 0.0254

1. 33.6529242569511deg - 33.13518696069031deg = 0.51773729626079deg
2. $1 deg * 111319.49079327358m/deg = 57634.2521844373683014174969282m
3. $2 m / 1536px = 37.52m/px
4. $3 m/px * (90px/in * 1in/0.0254m) = 132953.03

which gives a scale of 1:132953... not even close!

units all cancel great, but as you can see from the calculation the value is not even close to 250k.

Can anyone explain where I'm wrong?

**EDIT**
In case anyone else stumbles upon this the answer was hidden in the spec documents for CADRG. The DPI to use for CADRG is 169. Plug that in to the above equation and it works great for CADRG. You just need to know the correct DPI to use for the imagery you are trying to find the scale of and the above will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealing with CADRG the correct DPI to use is 169. This can be found on page 10 of the MIL-SPEC documentation. The math in the question is correct just plug in 169 instead of 90 for dpi.

Answer (score 0):

You need also the longitude because otherwise the map is distorted. IMO try the same formula with the longitude.

Comment: So i did this and i get 1:175976 for x and 1:132952 for y... didn't see how this got me closer to a solution (did not calculate in the fact that as latitude increases (decreases when south of equator) then the m/deg are less for longitude) so I thought maybe i need to take the area in account instead... I calculated that the real world area covered by the image was 4396586121 m^2 but the image covered only 0.187916470044 m^2 which gives a ridiculous ratio.